# PayPal show sandbox transactions

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to develop a monthly subscription system on my ASP.NET MVC 4 website. I m using [the PayPal .NET SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK)

To set up the subscription system, I created a billing plan and a billing agreement. I also created a PayPal sandbox account.

When I go in debug mode, everything works well, I m redirected to the PayPal sandbox website to accept the billing agreement, and then I back on my website to proceed to payment. The payment processing works without any error, but I don't know where I can get a trace of the fake transactions I made to verify if the payment process has really worked as expected.

Where can I find this information ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Besides the JasonZ's answer, you can actually get the list of all subscriptions/billing agreements by doing below (this is on the seller's account):

1. Go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com, and logging into the account with the sandbox account's email address and password
2. Go to 'Recurring payments dashboard' using this shortcut link: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_merchant-hub

This can be also used for REST API billing agreements as well

Comment: Thanks for this. When I login on sandbox.paypal.com using one of the buyers sandbox account I created, I m able to get a list of the test payments I've done. But, when I login using the seller's account, the received payments list is empty. I don't understand the logic behind this.

Comment: That's odd, I'm pretty sure the link above is for seller's side. For buyer's side, you can see it in 'My preapproved payments': https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_manage-paylist

Comment: By the way, you can navigate to the pages manually without using the shortcut, but it varies on the type of account you have

Answer (score 0):

The [REST API Test Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/dashboard/test) site ([PayPal Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/developer) > **Dashboard** > **Transactions**) should list all the recent transactions for your sandbox account.